# Need to show a like a form or inline editable after click the row of table in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Am very new to vaadin. I am fetching the data from a JSON file and showing the data in table form. If i want to edit ant value, after clicking on a row i should get  form with the values of that row. How can i achieve that in vaadin?

Here is my code,

```
public class MainView extends TabSheet implements View{

public static final String TITLE_ID = "proposals-title";

private Label titleLabel;

private Window window;

private Table grid;

private static final String ACTIVE = "active";
private static final String CONVERTED = "converted";
private static final String CANCELLED = "cancelled";
private final VerticalLayout root;
private CatalogDataProvider proposalDataProvider = new    
CatalogDataProvider(new FileDataProviderUtil());
private Object sortContainerPropertyId;

public MainView() {
    addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABSHEET_PADDED_TABBAR);
    root = new VerticalLayout();
    /*root.setSizeFull();*/
    root.setMargin(true);
    root.setCaption("All Proposals");


    addTab(root);

    Responsive.makeResponsive(root);
    root.addComponent(buildHeader());
    root.setSpacing(true);


    grid = new Table();

   grid.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent itemClickEvent) {
            final String title = "Details";

            final ProposalDetailsView proposalDetailsView = new 
     ProposalDetailsView("128", title);
            updateTable(proposalDetailsView);
            proposalDetailsView.getTextField_1();
            System.out.println(proposalDetailsView + 
          proposalDetailsView.getTextField_1().getValue().toString());
            addTab(proposalDetailsView).setClosable(true);
            setSelectedTab(getComponentCount() - 1);
            getTab(proposalDetailsView).setCaption(title);

        }

        private void updateTable(ProposalDetailsView 
           proposalDetailsView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });

    updateTable(ACTIVE);

    grid.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent itemClickEvent) {
            Notification.show("Clicked");
        }
    });

    //root.setSpacing(true);
    root.addComponent(grid);


    // All the open sub-windows should be closed whenever the root layout
    // gets clicked.
    root.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void layoutClick(final LayoutClickEvent event) {
       }
      });

     }


    public Component buildHeader() {
    HorizontalLayout header = new HorizontalLayout();
    header.setSpacing(true);

    titleLabel = new Label("Proposals");
    titleLabel.setId(TITLE_ID);
    titleLabel.setSizeUndefined();
    titleLabel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H1);
    titleLabel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_NO_MARGIN);
    header.addComponent(titleLabel);

    JSONArray proposal_classes = 
        proposalDataProvider.getCatalogClasses();
    HorizontalLayout tools = new HorizontalLayout();

    for(int i=0;i<proposal_classes.length();i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = proposal_classes.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = jsonObject.getInt("count");
            String name=jsonObject.getString("class");

            Button status_button=new Button(name+" ("+id+")");

      status_button.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS_COLORED);

            tools.addComponent(status_button);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    tools.setSpacing(true);

    tools.addStyleName("toolbar");
    header.addComponent(tools);

    return header;
    }

   public void updateTable(String catalogClass) {
    try {
        // Use the factory method of JsonContainer to instantiate the
        // data source for the table.

        JSONArray proposals = 
    proposalDataProvider.getCatalogs(catalogClass);

        JsonContainer dataSource = 
      JsonContainer.Factory.newInstance(proposals.toString());
        grid.setContainerDataSource(dataSource);

        grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
        grid.setVisibleColumns("productId", "name", "defaultPrice", 
    "dimension", "designer", "subcategory", "categoryId", 
      "subcategoryId", "defaultMaterial");
        grid.setColumnHeaders("Product ID #", "Name", "Status", 
      "Description","Dimension", "Designer", "subcategory", 
       "categoryId", "subcategoryId", "Def_material");
        grid.setWidth("98%");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {

    }
    }
   @Override
   public void enter(ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent) {
   }
   public Object getSortContainerPropertyId() {
    return sortContainerPropertyId;
    }
    }
```

=================================================

The below code is the view after clicking any row, here i need values of the selected row to edit/update

```
    public class ProposalDetailsView extends  EditCompositeView {
    private String proposalId;
    private String title;
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    public ProposalDetailsView(String proposalId, String title) {

    this.proposalId = proposalId;
    this.title = title;
   layout.setSizeFull();
   layout.addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_SCROLL_INDICATOR);
    layout.addComponent(buildHeader());
    }

    private Component buildHeader() {
    HorizontalLayout header = new HorizontalLayout();
    header.addStyleName("viewheader");
    header.setSpacing(true);
    Label titleLabel = new Label(this.title);
    titleLabel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H1);
    titleLabel.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_NO_MARGIN);
    header.addComponent(titleLabel);
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    MainView min = new MainView();
    getTextField_1().setValue(proposalId);
    getTextField_2().setValue(proposalId);

    return header;
    }

    }
```

A million Tons of Thanks in advance. Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

Comment: for inline table editing try following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142212/vaadin-table-row-inline-editing?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, But how to integrate that in my code @HaseebAnser ji. Can you please help in that ?

Comment: i will suggest you to use thee vaadin grid component instead of table bcz it will be more easy Reference: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-vaadin-grid

Comment: I have used Grid only now. But, in table it is only showing the 1st row data which is column header from JSON, But no data for the for those coloumns @HaseebAnser

Comment: then there must be some error in the step in which you are parsing the json data

Comment: But, it is take taking only like id,productid & name [
  {
    "id": "partridge-wardrobe",
    "productId": "partridge-wardrobe",
    "name": "Partridge Wardrobe",
   }]

Comment: the code is same code, just i made gridTable from table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109444/discussion-between-user3599302-and-haseeb-anser).